# HAR feature selection

Tags: signal-processing, feature-extraction, feature-selection, activity-recognition

I've been working on human activity recognition using a UCI dataset. 561 features are computed from the raw signals come from accelerometer and gyroscope. Based on these 561 features, a high accuracy is achieved. Now I intend to use less features to achieve comparable results, is there any algorithm I can implement to select the most significant features?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Your question will be closed because it’s too broad, but the terms you are looking for are [“dimensionality reduction”](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/unsupervised_reduction.html) and [“feature selection”](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html).

Comment: Principal component analysis maybe